# File htacces constantly erases its contents, what to do?

Tags: .htaccess, server

Does anybody know how to fix this?!
I create new account on my server, upload files but htaccess file keep deleting all its contents, i make changes and save but again i get empty htaccess. These same files are already on sites that work, on same server,  and there is no problems with htaccess

Comment: It should be a problem with your specific server. Have you already contacted their support?

Comment: The problem is solved, thanks